# Spark Cassandra connector control number of reads per sec

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am running spark application which performs a direct join on Cassandra table

I am trying to control the number of reads per sec, so that the long-running job doesn't impact the overall database
Here are my configuration parameters

```
--conf spark.cassandra.concurrent.reads=2
--conf spark.cassandra.input.readsPerSec=2
--conf spark.executor.cores=1
--conf spark.executor.instances=1
--conf spark.cassandra.input.fetch.sizeInRows=1500
```

I know I won't read more than 1500 rows from each partition
However, in spite of all thresholds reads per sec are crossing 200-300

Is there any other flag or configuration that needs to be turned on

Comment: what version of the connector?

Comment: 3.0.0 version. I tried changing all values just dosent seem to have any effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seams that `CassandraJoinRDD` has a bug in throttling with `spark.cassandra.input.readsPerSec`, see https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-627 for details.
In the meantime use `spark.cassandra.input.throughputMBPerSec` to throttle your join. Note that the throttling is based on [RateLimiter](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v3.0.0/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/writer/RateLimiter.scala#L11-L15) class, so the throttling won't kick in immediately (you need to read at least `throughputMBPerSec` of data to start throttling). This is something that may be improved in the SCC.

Comment: Thanks a lot  I will try with this